# Geting java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10062 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE."

Tags: java, android

Want to check Internet connection.Following is the code :

```
  public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkinfo != null){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Following is the xml file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vinitmandlesha.logintestform">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sample"
            android:label="sample"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Getting this exception on calling isNetworkConnected method.I have set all required permission in manifest file. Also the 3G connection is active on emulator. Where am I am going wrong ?

Comment: please post complete stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Permission tags ending is not proper that why permissions are not being applied in the app.

Answer (score 2):

Android permissions are case sensitive, so pl change

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

or .

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  
  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

.
Case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

and also check if you are running on Marshmallow, you have to give dynamic runtime permission for that